# Insert data using datagridview C# windows Application

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
 try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string constring = @"Data Source=ZEE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyBill;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO stock VALUES(@productname, @packing,@totalquantity,@rate,@expry,@dealername)", con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", row.Cells["pname"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@packing", row.Cells["packing"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalquantity", row.Cells["quantity"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", row.Cells["rate"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expry", row.Cells["exp"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dealername", row.Cells["dname"].Value);

                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");
    }
```

The above code insert Data properly but gridview auto generate new row which gives error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kcyi.png)

Comment: Code review: Don't disable pooling and don't recreate the connection and command in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this check after the foreach line

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

However I recommend to refactor a bit your code. Essentially you are rebuilding the connection, the command and all parameters at each loop. Instead you could build the connection, the command and the parameters before starting the loop. Inside the loop only change the parameter values and execute the query

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO stock VALUES(@productname, @packing,@totalquantity,@rate,@expry,@dealername)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@productname", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    .... all the other parameters follow....
    con.Open();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            cmd.Parameter["@productname"].Value = row.Cells["pname"].Value);
            ....
            .... set all other parameters with the row values
            ....
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe improve it another little bit using `if(row.IsNewRow) continue;` instead of having your whole code-block inside the `if`.

Comment: Why? There is some hidden advantage in this?

Comment: Not hidden. By reversing the if-statement you improve the readability of your code by reducing indentation. Also, nobody has to wonder what that `}` is doing at the end of all that code. It is a common suggestion when people offer advice on improving code readability.

Comment: See for instance [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/169751/133844) on codereviewSE

Comment: I don't agree with that. I prefer to reduce at minimum  statements like _break_ and _continue_ Not sure about the readability because I never put a lot of lines of code inside a for/while/if and prefer to add a sub or function also if it is called just once in that block. At the end of the day these are just preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You may check if row is empty before inserting. Also note that there is only one connection for all insertings:

```
string constring = @"Data Source=ZEE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyBill;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
    con.Open();

    foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var productName = row.Cells["pname"].Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName))
            continue;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO stock VALUES(@productname, @packing,@totalquantity,@rate,@expry,@dealername)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@packing", row.Cells["packing"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalquantity", row.Cells["quantity"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", row.Cells["rate"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expry", row.Cells["exp"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dealername", row.Cells["dname"].Value);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** It's better to check `IsNewRow` property as `Steve` suggests.

> DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow returns true if the row is the last row in
>   the DataGridView, which is used for the entry of a new row of data;
>   otherwise, false.